# Is a thermodynamic state variable the same as a Thermodynamic propertie and vice versa?

Tags: thermodynamics, complex-systems

Is a Thermodynamic propertie (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_thermodynamic_properties) the same as a state variable (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/State_variables) ? Also the properties site says:

> In thermodynamics, a physical property is any property that is
> measurable, and whose value describes a state of a physical system.
> Thermodynamic properties are defined as characteristic features of a
> system, capable of specifying the system's state.

It does not use the term "state variable" anywhere. But actually

> whose value describes a state of a physical system

means nothing else than the state variables, doesn't it? So can we say "state variable" = "system property"? So all those properties in the list are State Variables?

[image]

So this gives a complete list of all thermodynamic system variables?

Answer (score 0):

A thermodynamic property, let's call it $X$, might also have an equivalent state variable that can be used alongside other state variables to describe the equilibrium states of some system. However, these are not the same thing. A property is anything you can measure about a system, either locally (measuring the property at every point, like you would for an intensive property) or globally (of the whole system, like you would for extensive properties).

The fact that you can measure properties locally clearly indicates that they are not the same thing as state variables. State variables account for the whole system in its equilibrium state. Thus, the property $X$ we mentioned is the same for all points: $X_A=X_B \ \ \forall A,B$.

You can use intensive properties of a system as state variables, as long as you consider that they are homogeneous for the extent of the system. For example, in atmospheric physics, it's common to describe an air parcel using this version of the idel gas law: $p=\frac{R}{M}\rho T$; where $\rho$ is the density of the air and $T$ it's temperature, both intensive properties (as well as its pressure).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137687/discussion-on-answer-by-agaminon-is-a-thermodynamic-state-variable-the-same-as-a).